# Optimize Query with subquery on the same table

Tags: sql-server

I have an Employee table and another one EmployeeManager, I need to do a query to show all employees that are not managers and another one that shows all employees that are managers.

This is the first query:

```
SELECT E.EmployeeId, E.FirstName, E.LastName
  FROM Employee E
 INNER JOIN (SELECT a.EmployeeId,
                (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EmployeeManager b 
                      WHERE a.EmployeeId = b.Managerid) IsManager
               FROM EmployeeManager a) ER
    ON E.EmployeeId = ER.EmployeeId
   AND ER.IsManager = 0
```

Is there any better option? because I don't like at all.

Comment: why don't you like this?

Comment: Good question @HLGEM.. OP: Can you show some data or a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**All Employees that are Managers:**

```
SELECT   E.EmployeeId, E.FirstName, E.LastName
FROM     Employee E
JOIN     EmployeeManager M ON E.EmployeeId = M.ManagerId
```

**All Employees that are *not* Managers:**

```
SELECT   EmployeeId, FirstName, LastName
FROM     Employee
WHERE    EmployeeId NOT IN 
         (
             SELECT   ManagerId 
             FROM     EmployeeManager 
             WHERE    ManagerId IS NOT NULL
         )
```

*Note: I added the `WHERE ManagerId IS NOT NULL` due to a comment from **@usr** that suggested NULLs may be allowed for `ManagerId`, which would cause the `NOT IN` to fail.  Without knowing the schema, this covers that scenario.*

Comment: Clean, minimal and fast. +1. But: The NOT IN will not work due to NULL values. Filter them out.

Comment: @usr - I'm not following.  Wouldn't it only be pulling Employees who aren't in the EmployeeManager table?  Where are the NULL values coming from?

Comment: Maybe EmployeeManager.ManagerId can contain nulls. If there is just one NULL, the NOT IN will never match anything.

Comment: @usr - I assumed it was an identity column, but just incase you are right, I edited the post since we don't know what they OP's schema is.